# Select part of a polygon on one side of a line QGIS

Tags: qgis, buffer

I have a line shapefile of the outline of a water body. It was created by conversion of the polygon to line.

I am looking to add a layer of 500m standoff from the shore into the lake.

I have added a negative buffer of -500m, and that gives me the area which is accessible, however I want to just have that 500m as a polygon.

A picture speaks a 1000 words. See below.[image]

What I am looking for is a polygon of the purple area.  When I buffer the line it buffers both sides, I just want one side.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bingo.  Figured it out. Thanks Sorbus for the attempt but was not good to me.

What i ended up doing was using the clip tool on the 500m buffer of both sides of the line and using the original lake polygon as the clip layer.  clipped to all areas within the polygon.

Answer (score 1):

The [MMQGIS](http://michaelminn.com/linux/mmqgis/) plugin allows you to produce one-sided line buffers. Install it from within QGIS. It will handle multiple lines at once, with the option of north, south, east and west facing buffers.